# How can I debug my Python code to check if data can form a triangle or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, cpython

The aim of the code is to find whether it is possible to form a triangle with the given arguments. The theory tells that **the sum of the two arbitrary sides should be greater than the third side** and according to I am coding but it is not showing the correct answer.

My task is to return **True** if the arguments make it possible and return **False** if it is not.

```
def isItATriangle(a, b, c):
    if a + b > c or a + c > b or b + c > a:
        return True

    else:
        return False

print(isItATriangle(1 , 1, 3))
```

Why the code does not works properly?

Instead of

```
if a + b > c or a + c > b or b + c > a:
            return True

        else:
            return False
```

The main right code shows this

```
if a + b <= c:
        return False
    if b + c <= a:
        return False
    if c + a <= b:
        return False
    return True
```

How can I determine in which part of logic I am wrong?

Comment: Your `or`s should be `and`s. Try your function with the arguments (10,1,1).

Comment: It's unrelated to your issue (which khelwood has diagnosed properly), but I'd note that instead of `if some_condition: return True else: return False`, you can just do `return some_condition` (or maybe `bool(some_condition)` if you really need a bool value and don't have one already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return true you must fulfill *all* the conditions, not only one of them. Because of that, your code should be:

```
def isItATriangle(a, b, c):
    if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
        return True

    else:
        return False

print(isItATriangle(1 , 1, 3))
```

This is, changing your `or` for an `and`. You can learn more about Python logical operators [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators) or [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Corrected and simplified:

```
def isItATriangle(a, b, c):
    return a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:

print(isItATriangle(1 , 1, 3))
```